# How to edit, radio button fillable PDF with PDFrw

Tags: python, pdfrw

for a project I will need to autofill over 1000 pdf forms and in the form there is radio button:
I found a code:

```
def radio_button(annotation, value):
for each in annotation['/Kids']:
    # determine the export value of each kid
    keys = each['/AP']['/N'].keys()
    keys.remove('/Off')
    export = keys[0]

    if f'/{value}' == export:
        val_str = pdfrw.objects.pdfname.BasePdfName(f'/{value}')
    else:
        val_str = pdfrw.objects.pdfname.BasePdfName(f'/Off')
    each.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(AS=val_str))

annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(V=pdfrw.objects.pdfname.BasePdfName(f'/{value}')))
```

It did not really worked out, since I was wondering what the value would be as well as the annotion.

here is the website I used.

Does someone has any ideas?

Comment: https://westhealth.github.io/exploring-fillable-forms-with-pdfrw.html

Comment: Please edit your question and put the link in the question instead of in a comment, see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)